# EdgeRing::computePoints: found null Directed Edge

Tags: r, sf

I'm attempting to compare the global population density of cities excluding bodies of water.

To do this I'm working with a shapefile of global water bodies taken from [here](http://gis.ess.washington.edu/data/vector/worldshore/index.html). I've projected into mollweide consistent with the Global Human Settlement Layer's CRS:

```
 CRS arguments: +proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

When I try and crop the water bodies I get the following error:

```
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: EdgeRing::computePoints: found null Directed Edge.
```

st_is_valid() is True.

I've tried changing precision and making valid but this does not help:

`st_set_precision(500000) %>%  st_make_valid()`

I've narrowed the huge dataaset down to one row which causes the issue for this particular bounding box, but I imagine this problem might recurr with other parts of the dataset, so I seek a general solution.

[Link to RDS file with problematic geometry](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rIgo8FgNysSn5IMld_0OGEFmvIvAWBfH/view?usp=share_link)

Here's the bounding box for reference

```
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 11781630 
xmax       : 11982630 
ymin       : 1697156 
ymax       : 1898156
```

Comment: Just thinking that maybe the null directed edge could mean two consecutive points at the same location. Try to simplify with tolerance of 0.

Comment: st_simply() worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If source data contains consecutive points at the same place the process that creates the graph may try to create edges also between the duplicate vertices. Consecutive points can be removed for example by simplifying the geometries with tolerance=0.